# How to stop genyMotion crashing on intents?

Tags: android, android-intent, genymotion

so I'm using the genyMotion emulator, but I have a bunch of intents I don't use right away, and somehow it keeps on crashing(and gives me a null pointer exception)! On my real android device it runs fine and i dont get the exception.. here's some example code. Can someone help plz!?!?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


    private Intent storeRightintent = new Intent(this, Istanbul_Folder.class);//I KEEP GETTING NULL POINT EXCEPTION HERE!!!


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        storeRightintent = new Intent(this, Istanbul_Folder.class);

        //Buttons
        View folderButton = (View) findViewById(R.id.folder_button);
        folderButton.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        View createButton = (View) findViewById(R.id.MycreateButton);
        createButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
```

Logcat:

```
Process: com.lorentzos.swipecards.example, PID: 7303
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.lorentzos.swipecards.example/com.lorentzos.swipecards.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
            at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
            at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3813)
            at com.lorentzos.swipecards.MyActivity.<init>(MyActivity.java:45)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you have Istanbul_Folder class?

Comment: Yeah i have an instanbul class

Comment: its not this class, but when I go to other classes that have intents, it crashes on those as well..

Comment: Which class do you have: `Instanbul` or `Instanbul_Folder`?

Comment: @RaymondLukanta its Instanbul_folder

Comment: Have you declared Istanbul_Folder on your `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: @RaymondLukanta Yeah, like i said it works on my phone but not on genymotion, so its a genymotion problem I feel

Comment: Is it still error if you change 
`private Intent storeRightintent = new Intent(this, Istanbul_Folder.class);//I KEEP GETTING NULL POINT EXCEPTION HERE!!!`
to 
`private Intent storeRightintent;`?

Comment: @RaymondLukanta wow..that worked...I feel so dumb.. but still I don't get why geny motion crashes with that and my phone doesn't. Oh well. thanks bud!

Answer (score 1):

Change `private Intent storeRightintent = new Intent(this, Istanbul_Folder.class);//I KEEP GETTING NULL POINT EXCEPTION HERE!!!` 
to `private Intent storeRightintent;`

Because I suspect, the `this` at that line has not been initialized.